# Disp difference between A and B when B is not NaN

Tags: matlab

A have two matrices `<1x100 double>` that I `plot(A,B)`. In some columns of matrix B there is a NaN. What I want to do is to get the difference (like A is 5 higher than B) between A an B where both A and B exists. I want it to be presented as a local maximum, simply by printing it out with `disp`.

Example: When max(A) = 20 and B = 10 I want to display: A is 10 more than B. Then when A changes to 30 once again I want to display: max(A) is 20 more than B.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use `nanmax(B)` or `max(B(~isnan(B)))`.

Comment: i feel like you posted this twice so please consider closing the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ValidData = ~isnan(A) & ~isnan(B); % Get all indices where both exist
plot(A(ValidData),B(ValidData));
```

[`isnan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) gives you all elements which are `NaN`, negate this (`~`), and you will get all non-NaN values. This then can be used as a logical index for both `A` and `B`.

To get maximum values, do as AndrasDeak [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074377/disp-difference-between-a-and-b-when-b-is-not-nan/38074573#comment63585583_38074377)

```
nanmax(A-B)
```

Update: apparently `max` has now as default to omit NaN values, so you can use that directly:

```
[MaxValue,MaxPosition] = max(A-B);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure wheter you want to ignore the nan and cut down the vector to numbers or just ignore the parts where one of the values is nan. For the latter case:

```
%show you the difference
C=A-B
% ~ means you ignore that output, and the second output of max is the postion
[~,position]=max(A-B);
disp(['At Position ' num2str(position) ' A is ' num2str(A(position)) ' and ' num2str(A(position)-B(position)) ' bigger than B'])
```